# Reactive programming in Domain Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, reactive-programming

I'm used to develop software creating "domain entities" -- these entities "depends" only on other entities inside the domain.

Let's say I have this interface

```
package domain;

import domain.beans.City;

public interface CitiesRepository {  
  City get(String cityName);          
}
```

As you can see, the `City` I am returning is again a domain object. Implementations of this `CitiesRepository` can be found outside the domain, and can rely upon a database, an http client, a cached decorator etc.

I am now working with a reactive framework -- vert.x -- and I am trying to understand how I can keep working using such model. I don't want  vert.x specific answer but only to understand if there is any pattern/best practice to understand how to achieve this.

In the reactive-programming there is almost never a return value but always some callback/handler that will consume the event after it happened. Should I rewrite my interfaces to be "reactive"?

```
package domain;

import domain.beans.City;

public interface CitiesRepository {  
  void get(String cityName, DomainHandler<City> cityHandler);
}
```

Just providing this example caused me some some spaghetti-headache when thinking to the implementations where I have to deal with the Handler of the "reactive framework" to "fill" my domain handler.

Should I stop thinking in this kind of design when working with reactive model? Should I prefer an Observable/Promise approach?

Any hint would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the reactive systems I've been involved with there has been an event handler that would then use the repository:

```
public void SomeEventHandler : IHandle<SomeEvent> {
public SomeEventHandler(CityRepository repo) {}
}
```

You would then use your existing repository inside the handler code:

```
public void When(SomeEvent event) {
    var city = _cityRepository.Get(event.CityName);
// do something with city
}
```

In the CompositionRoot of the application, the handler would be registered to handle the event through whatever messaging bus / reactive stream etc. will be receiving / producing the event.

So I wouldn't look to make the repository reactive, rather add in an event handler to use it.

Answer (score 0):

With reactive design you add a layer of indirection of how the API is invoked and you specify that in addition to your original vanilla spec. The reason is, in async design it matters a lot how you invoke stuff and it is not always one size fits all, so better to not make early big decisions, or bind "what it is/does" to "how it does it".

There are three common tools for making things asynchronous:

- future/promise
- callback
- message passing

Future/promise is the most binding of the three in terms of the whole design and is usually the most hairy on the implementation side and you need to do a lot of moves to prevent ABA bugs in your design and to truck futures which are still running something, but no one needs the results. Yes, they abstract away concurrency, are monadic etc., but they make you their hostage the moment you add the first one and they are quite hard to get rid of.

Callback is the fastest in a single process, but to make them work with actor-based system or across wires you inevitably are going to use messages. Moreover, the moment you need a first state machine you need event queue and messages right away. So to be most future proof, the safest path is to just go with messages. Moving between message and callback is very straightforward (when possible at all) for how simple both these mechanisms are.

A protocol to lookup city by key could be something like this:

```
protocol Requests
message GetCityRequest(name): Requests

protocol Responses
message GetCityResponse(cityMaybe): Responses
```

But knowing this topic really well, I'd say invest into the "state replication pattern" in generic form and use it for both simple static lookups and dynamic subscriptions. It is not hard to get it right and it will be your main working horse for most of your system needs.